# jquery add '<li></li>' and place cursor at the end of '<li>{cursor here}'

Tags: jquery

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/abmjd2ze/4/

```
<textarea rows="12" cols="10">Go to the end of text and press Enter.</textarea>
```

jquery

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
if(ev.keyCode == 13){

var caretPos = this.selectionStart;//detects cursor position before Enter
var textAreaTxt = this.value;//whole text of the textarea
var txtToAdd = "\n<li></li>";
$(this).val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );//set new value of textbox
var sePos = caretPos + txtToAdd.length;//Also detects some position

this.setSelectionRange(sePos,sePos-5);

}//if(ev.keyCode == 13){
});//$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
```

Problem is with `this.setSelectionRange(sePos,sePos-5);`

As result I get

```
<li>
{cursor here}</li>
```

but want

```
<li>{cursor here}
</li>
```

If change to `this.setSelectionRange(sePos,sePos-6);`

Then get

```
<li
{cursor here}></li>
```

Is it possible to add some short code to get the cursor in necessary position? If long code then better to leave as it is

**Solution**
Oh, very simple solution
Just need to add `ev.preventDefault();`
and I spend so much time to find solution... oh

Comment: you should post the solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: If you solved the problem you should post it as an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro, It worked...

Just add `ev.preventDefault();`

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
if(ev.keyCode == 13){

var caretPos = this.selectionStart;
var textAreaTxt = this.value;
var txtToAdd = "\n<li></li>";
$(this).val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );//set new value of textbox
var sePos = caretPos + txtToAdd.length;
this.setSelectionRange(sePos,sePos-5);
ev.preventDefault();  //<--------------------Add Here...
}//if(ev.keyCode == 13){
});//$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
```

Hope it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Appears very simple solution

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
if(ev.keyCode == 13){

//just need to add this code
ev.preventDefault();

var caretPos = this.selectionStart;//detects cursor position before Enter
var textAreaTxt = this.value;//whole text of the textarea
var txtToAdd = "\n<li></li>";
$(this).val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );//set new value of textbox
var sePos = caretPos + txtToAdd.length;//Also detects some position
this.setSelectionRange(sePos,sePos-5);

}//if(ev.keyCode == 13){
});//$('textarea').keydown(function(ev){
```